# How to refresh columns of KendoUI/Angular grid

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

According to Kendo UI/Angular documentation ([see here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/introduction#delaying-widget-initialization)), the grid does not support re-defining the columns after the widget is instantiated. That's why Kendo provides a `k-ng-delay` keyword. This works fine, however I need to re-define grid columns many times, not only once. Is there a way to recreate the grid programmatically in Angular? Or any other ideas on how to re-define the grid columns several times?

Comment: As per my understanding there is no direct way to do so, but you can remove the element (grid) from that div / parent and recreate the whole grid with the new configuration or columns and data.

Comment: How to recreate the grid in angular? Using jquery?

Comment: I am not that familiar with angular, so can't comment on how to achieve grid recreation. However using Jquery / JS its much simpler.

Comment: possible duplicate of [KendoGrid/Angular: cannot create grid columns/data dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28501944/kendogrid-angular-cannot-create-grid-columns-data-dynamically)

Comment: is there any updates? I have same issue . I have grid in angular and two buttons ones bind 5 column the other bind 2 but when i click them grid always shows 5 column.... How to fix this?

Comment: @saulyasar what version of Angular you are using?

Comment: i fixed my issue as in link thnx @ps0604 https://www.telerik.com/forums/refresh-grid-columns-after-data-change

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the ***k-rebind*** attribute to get the widget automatically updated when some scope variable changes:

For example:

```
<div kendo-grid="grid" k-options="gridOptions" k-rebind="gridOptions">
</div>
```

In this case, I have specified that if the gridOptions scope variable is updated, the grid needs to be destroyed and recreated.

I've created a demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/sMaIMfrEw5hFRLzFpXvn

[More information about k-rebind](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/introduction#updating-widgets-when-options-change)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried to use k-rebind but had lots of problems, ended up wrapping a jQuery KendoGrid in a directive

Comment: your solution work properly but ... <kendo-grid id="grid" options="mainGridOptions"> </kendo-grid> does not worked

Comment: is there any way without using js? I have same issue . I have grid in angular and two buttons ones bind 5 column the other bind 2 but when i click them grid always shows 5 column.... How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on Paulo Soto's answer (Thank you!)

I'm auto-generating columns and this is how i rebind to a completely new resultset + column schema:

`var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
$scope.mainGridOptions.columns = columnSchema.COLUMNS;
$scope.mainGridOptions.dataSource.schema = columnSchema.SCHEMA;
$scope.mainGridOptions.dataSource.data = data;`

Grid looks like this:

```
<kendo-grid id="grid" class="qs-site-plannerGrid" k-options="mainGridOptions" k-rebind="mainGridOptions">    </kendo-grid>
```